# Elementary reasoning question on solving an equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

The aim is to solve
$$
\cos z = \cosh z \qquad (*)
$$
for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

---

Typically one finds necessary condition on $z$ so that (*) is satisfied.
Then we check that the condition is sufficient: the  $z$ we found satisfy $(*)$.

---

Below I want to reason by equivalence, so I want to merge both implications.

I know there exists at least one solution $z\in \mathbb{C}$ to $\cos z = \cosh z$.

Here is my reasoning with $x=\exp(iz)$ and $y=\exp(z)$, $z=a+ib$
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
      &\cos z = \cosh z \Leftrightarrow x + \frac{1}{x} = y+ \frac{1}{y}
      \underset{xy\neq 0}{\Leftrightarrow}
      x^2y + y = xy^2 +x
      \Leftrightarrow 
       xy(x-y) + y-x=0
      \\
      &\Leftrightarrow (x-y)(xy-1)=0
      \Leftrightarrow x=y \text{ or } xy=1
      \Leftrightarrow\exp(iz) = \exp(z) \text{ or } \exp((i+1)z)=1
      \\
      &\Leftrightarrow \exp(ia)\exp(-b) = \exp(a)\exp(ib)  \text{ or } \exp(i(a+b))\exp(a-b)=1 
      \\
      &\Leftrightarrow \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{ll}
          a=-b
          \\
          a=b + 2k\pi, \ k\in \mathbb{Z}
        \end{array}
      \right.
      \text{ or } 
      \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{ll}
          a=b
          \\
          a=-b +2k\pi, \ k\in \mathbb{Z}
        \end{array}
      \right.
      \\
      &\Leftrightarrow \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{ll}
          a=-b
          \\
          a= k\pi, \ k\in \mathbb{Z}
        \end{array}
      \right.
      \text{ or } 
      \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{ll}
          a=b
          \\
          a=k\pi, \ k\in \mathbb{Z}
        \end{array}
      \right.
\end{array}
$$

I should have write an implication instead of an equivalence somewhere, but I cannot find where.
Otherwise it would mean that $z=k\pi (i+1), k\in \mathbb{Z}$ is solution of $(*)$ which is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ or $z\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: corrected thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch from $z$ to $x,y$, you drop the relation $x^i=y$ and draw conclusions as if they were independent.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we have the integer solution $z=0$.

Your solutions are correct, we have $z=(1+i)k\pi$ and $z=(1-i)k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Indeed we have for example when $z=(1+i)k\pi$:

$$\cos((1+i)k\pi)=\cos(k\pi)\cos(ik\pi)-\sin(k\pi)\sin(ik\pi)$$
$$=\cos(k\pi)\cosh(k\pi)$$

and $$\cosh((1+i)k\pi)=\cosh(k\pi)\cosh(ik\pi)+\sinh(k\pi)\sinh(ik\pi)$$
$$=\cosh(k\pi)\cos(k\pi)+i\sinh(k\pi)\sin(k\pi)$$
$$=\cos(k\pi)\cosh(k\pi)$$

as required, where we have used that $\cosh(iz)=\cos(z)$, $\sinh(iz)=i\sin(z)$ and the angle addition formulas. Similarly for $z=(1-i)k\pi.$